# CSS overflow hidden and absolute position

Tags: html, css

Consider following simple menu markup (automatically generated, and I do not have much control over it):

```css
.menu {
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /* overflow: hidden ... problem */
}
li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
ul li .submenu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100px;
}
ul li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Submenu
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>Sub item 1</li>
      <li>Sub item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>consectetur</li>
  <li>adipiscing elit</li>
  <li>Aliquam elit nisi</li>
  <li>pharetra quis</li>
  <li>nulla eget</li>
</ul>
```

In the above code, the menu has a fixed width, but it has more items than can fit in that width, so the rest of the items will go on the second line. I want to display only the items which can fit in first line, and want to hide the rest of them.

For that purpose I want to specify the height for the menu. I am using this CSS for the menu:

```
.menu {
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden; /* problem */
}
```

**Problem** is that The above css hides the `.submenu` items too. Please see the demo to understand the problem.

[image]

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lgyg2a4r/

Comment: Why dont you apply styling to your sub menu to make it look more like a drop down. Background, border, drop-shadow

Comment: How will the user ever get to the items that appear on the second line?

Comment: Do you have the means to add a class to all of the items that are on the second line?

Comment: @MCMXCII if there's no other way to control the height of the menu, then yes that can be a possibility too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your problem, you could use `white-space: nowrap` on the menu and `display: inline-block` on its immediate children. This forces all menu items on one line and they extend past the right edge of the window.

However, this will force a horizontal scrollbar. Depending on your situation, you can add `overflow-x: hidden` on the element that contains the menu. That element must have other content so that it is taller than the tallest submenu.

```css
#wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  min-height: 400px;
}
.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: palevioletred;
}
.menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  background-color: paleturquoise;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>Submenu
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>Sub item 1</li>
        <li>Sub item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>consectetur</li>
    <li>adipiscing elit</li>
    <li>Aliquam elit nisi</li>
    <li>pharetra quis</li>
    <li>nulla eget</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following way you can do it without need of JQuery. Remove `position:relative` from `li`. And remove `left`, `top` from `submenu` and use negative `margin` will make trick.

```css
.menu {
    width: 500px;
    height: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
     overflow: hidden  /* problem */
}

li {
    float: left;    
    margin-right: 30px;
}

ul li .submenu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
   list-style: none;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: -40px;
}

ul li:hover .submenu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    <li >Submenu
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>Sub item 1</li>
            <li>Sub item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>consectetur</li>
    <li>adipiscing elit</li>
    <li>Aliquam elit nisi</li>
    <li>pharetra quis</li>
    <li>nulla eget</li>
</ul>
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgyg2a4r/4/)

Note: not reliable but good to solve problem.

Comment: Note that you removed the `left` offset from `.submenu`, which is critical to making this work.  A few words of explanation would be in order. Only downside may be cross-browser issues.

Comment: You have removed relative positioning from the main menu items. Ouch.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with the help of jQuery `$(this).position();`

```
$('li').hover(function(){
        var li = $(this).position();
        $(this).children('ul').css({
            left: li.left,
            top : li.top+20
        }).fadeToggle();
});
```

and remove the `position relative` from li

**[Working File](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgyg2a4r/5/)**

Comment: if you remove position relative and left: 0 you would achieve the same without jquery

Comment: @Escobear  yes but it may be cross browser issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to add a class to the items you want to hide on hover (the second line), try something like this:

```
......
<li class="sec">Aliquam elit nisi</li>
<li class="sec">pharetra quis</li>
<li class="sec">nulla eget</li>
......
```

CSS

```
ul li:hover ~ li.sc {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear enough, the mark up is automatically generated, and I do not have much control over it

Comment: Ahhh, in which case is the desired solution to remove the elements on the second line or to just make it so they don't cover up the submenu?